# WSO2 AM - adding custom validation before invoking the backend service

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

*Scenario*
I have configured the API in WSO2 which connects to my back-end HTTP service.

Before calling my back-end service, I want to call another HTTP end point (XML over HTTP) to perform some validations. If the validation response is success then the back end point configured in the API gateway can be invoked else the API needs to return error. Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Thanks,
Karthi

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom in sequence in your API https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Mediation+Extensions and handle that particular logic there.

In the In sequence, you can add a call mediator https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Call+Mediator to call the Back end and following that you may add a filter mediator https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Filter+Mediator and validate the response  and proceed the mediation flow based on it.

In the filter mediator, you may implement a logic to respond back from there itself if it is an error else do nothing so that it will proceed and call you API back end.